# What IAP type Should be Used for Magazine App Like Zinio?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, in-app-purchase

we have created a publishing platform that is similar to Zinio, 
We have a website where we upload magazines, and publish them to our mobile App on iPad

Apple is rejecting the App for the following reason:

Apps that use IAP to purchase items must assign the correct Purchasability type  We found that the Purchasability Type for one or more of your In App Purchase products was inappropriately set, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.

Your In App Purchases are set to Consumable.

However, based on product functionality, it would be more appropriate to use the  Non-Consumable In App Purchase type. Non-consumable products are only purchased once by users  and are always available on all devices that are associated with that user's iTunes account.

We have Replied and Explained them Several Times the following:

We are using consumable type of in-app products since we have a lot and frequently released magazines with different prices therefore we cannot define the purchases to be non-consumable.

We have set pricing Tiers from $0.99 until $54.99 so that each magazine will be classified appropriately and assigned to a certain Tier.

our system has a lot of magazines where each one has many issue releases. Magazines issues are sold within an offer.

We have "single issue offers" (offers containing only one magazine issue) and "multiple issues offers" (offers containing multiple isses, eg: get 3 digital issues of magazine x for $19.99).

We are using the Tiers from 1 to 55 to assign prices for our offers. Note here that the in-app purchases are consumable but our system won't let the user buy an already purchased item another time.

The application will contact our server each time when the user attemps to buy an offer.

If the offer is already bought, the application won't proceed with the in-app purchase and the user will be shown that he has already bought that offer.

Anyone has an answer to solve this problem?

As apple is insisting that we should not use consumables and use non-consumables which is not logical, as we need to be submitting the app every time magazines has been added to the system.

Help is Much Appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For magazines, you are unlikely to get consumable in-app purchase ability from Apple.   They've made it clear in the past that the expectations for media, levels, and content of this type are expected to be present on all of the users devices.

However, based on your description of what you are trying to do, I'm not sure that this is a problem. Remember that consumables are not the same as subscriptions, in that a subscription gives you access to potentially more than one issue, whereas a consumable just means that is something that may not be available after you purchase it, I.e. that it might be consumed.

It sounds like the real problem here is a catalog issue.   For episodic content, such as magazines, you don't want to hard-code your in-app purchases, instead look at the server-based model, as described in: 
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html

With this model, your server can return a list of product identifiers that meet certain criteria, so you don't have to constantly update the app.

Comment: We dont provide subscriptions for our users yet, 
they are only able to purchase offers that contain existing magazines in the system.
Basically each offer has multi magazine, but does not offer a future releases of the magazines as in the subscription, so basically setting as a subscription doesnt make sense, as we dont want our customers to pay in advance for something that already exist in our system

Comment: Understood, but I don't think it would change anything I wrote above. I wasn't suggesting you do a subscription, I was suggesting that you use a server-based IAP mechanism, which would allow you to add new items at will via your server and change the "inventory" of available items.  Consumables are for things that get "used up", like coins in a game, or something of that type.